# Optimizing database calls in an Excel Add In

Tags: c#, dll, excel, formula, vba

I am writing a DLL in .NET (C#) which can be loaded as a plugin in Excel. The DLL will provide many functions which can be used as formulas in Excel, to lookup certain values from the database of an external application.

For each of these formula functions, the DLL will need to access the database, so there will be too many database calls. For example, if Formula 1 is used in 10 cells, and a Formula 2 is used in 20 cells, there will be 30 calls to the database

Is there a way I can make a single call for each formula to the database? Any implementation ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Basically I am trying to write a generic DLL (Excel Plugin) which can be used by any user using Excel and a specific 3rd party accounting software. Each formula which the user inserts into Excel, will query the 3rd party app database and return a specific value, depending on the parameters passed.

For example, user can use a formula to query the ledger balance for a particular ledger, or use another formula to query the stock balance of a SKU, etc. I will have different categories of formulas, like ledger based formulas, SKU based formulas, etc. User can design side by side comparison reports, to show ledger balances for Quarter 1 and Quarter 2 in separate columns, etc.

This plugin is intended to act like a Report Designer (without any wizard, only formula-based), where user can design own reports in Excel, format them the way they want, and pull values from accounting software into any cell they want.

However, instead of evaluating each formula by reading from database every time, I wanted to first design a "formula exeuction plan", so I could club multiple calls to the database into a single call for a single formula, where I could pass all the parameters the user has specified in all instances of that formula in the Excel sheet.

Else, the Excel sheet will take a really long time to evaluate the formulas, making it impractical. I anticipate around 100 formulas on an average in a report.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what data you are trying to receive you could return sets of data in the code and map from the data set to the formula instead of running back to the database each time. So if you were say grabbing stock quotes or something you could grab all of the "WHERE" items and throw them into an IN clause when querying to the database. Once you have a dataset of the relevant updates you can send from the dataset instead of the database. Recalcs would grab run to the database again but through one call.

You could extend the cells for update flags and only refresh from those.

Pause calculations on the formula and only refresh when you have to.

Just thinking out loud..or whatever the typing equivalent is.

Edits:
I got down to the mechanics of it in my brain and I realized I'm out of my element. Sorry. I've never created a .DLL or an Addin with VS so everything after this is purely speculation and guesswork that may or may not cause more harm than good.

I'm thinking the UDF's execution will need to be re-routed until the execution plan is executed.

You would need a few objects.

1. ExecutionPlan - This object would manage lists of your queries. Either bulked or single transactions. You would need a method to convert the request to sql. Then pass the sql to the database in one call.
2. DataCache - Which would be a recordset of all the returned data. I'd encapsulate that with a flag or something to say if it was fetched or not.

The formula would go something like (psuedocode)

```
 if(dataCache.executed)
      formula.returnValue = dataCache.value(valueYouWantToReturn)
 else
      executePlan.add(valueYouWantToGet);
      formula.returnValue = "queued";
```

Then you would need to force a recalculation (that would cause all 100 formulas to go to the datastore (dataCache) to get its value after the dataCache went to the database once.

Your sql converter will be essentially building gigantic `IN` clause or a bunch of chaned `OR` through string building. So you have a clause for Ledger values that when the ExecutionPlan.Add method is called adds to the Ledger's select statement the value you want to retrieve.

Then then when ExecutionPlan.Execute is called. It will execute the sql statement, drop it in a recordset for you to index over when your dataCache.getValue(value) is called. You would search for the "value" and send it back to the function.

I'm explaining it to death, but I think it would work? I think...

Comment: I have edited my question to give more details about the intended use of DLL and some usecases. Grabbing all the data is not possible, as an accounting application's database will have huge no. of rows in each table. Any other ideas?

Comment: Edited answer with new stuff.

Comment: Hmm..But what will trigger the database call? Excel will just call my functions to get the formula results. If my DLL keeps on adding it in Execution Plan, when will I finally go to the database? What will trigger ExecutionPlan.Execute? If I somehow cache all formulas in an execution plan, and later evaluate them, how will I force the result back into the Excel sheet, because as far as Excel is concerned, it has already evaluated the formula and displayed the result! Basically how do I force the recalculation, since the result is already displayed as "Queued"?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the CUBEVALUE and other CUBE functions in Excel.  The CUBEVALUE function already does what your DLL is intended to do -- pull in a single value from an external database per function.  The catch is that the source data needs to be in OLAP form and responsive to MDX rather than SQL.

However this is not all that difficult to set up, although it is beyond the scope of this reply.  Fortunately, accounting tends to fit neatly into OLAP cubes -- you can set up dimensions for Date, Department, Account, etc.  Or for inventory, you can set dimensions on Item, Location, Status (on order, shipped, in-stock) etc.

It's worth looking into, at least.